# Find element id when drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I use drag and drop on Android. I have an element which could be drag and drop. This element can be drop at different position. I can retrieve the X and Y position where the user drop the element.

But, I can't retrieve which element is under the drop...
I have try some solutions but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Is there an easy way to find the element id of the element under the drop ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Maybe set a tag on the item when you drag it and retrieve the tag when you drop it, then do the logic based on the tag.

Comment: I have set some boolean for each end position, when I hit "ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED", boolean goes to true and when I hit "ACTION_DRAG_EXITED", boolean goes to false. It seems to work :)

Comment: You can post the solution here for other people having the same problem ;)